# Mi mapa de google no se muestra en el div

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Quiero insertar un mapa de google para captar coordenadas en mi pagina html pero el mapa no se muestra en el div, estoy haciendo uso de mi api de google, he revisado varias veces y he realizado algunos cambios al llamar la función para iniciar el mapa pero sigue sin mostrarse.

Este es el div en el que debe mostrarse:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%;" onload="initialize();">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.701327, -89.224434),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.701327, -89.224434),
            draggable: true
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            $("#txtLat").val(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
            $("#txtLng").val(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

            map.panTo(evt.latLng);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
            $("#txtLat").val(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
            $("#txtLng").val(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

            map.panTo(evt.latLng);
            marker.setPosition(evt.latLng);
        });

        map.setCenter(marker.position);

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El atributo `onload` solo está permitido en las siguientes etiquetas:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> y <style>
```

Es por eso que tu función `initialize()` nunca se llama.

De todas maneras lo normal es que el `onload` sea usado en el body. También es más que recomendable no usar los atributos de eventos en las etiquetas, sino usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initalize);
```